# I was trying binomial coeffecient problem using dp. i know its not an efficient approach bugt i wamt to know whats this SIGFPE error

Tags: decoding

Program I wrote. ran it on practice environment of gfg:

```
class Solution{
public:
    int nCr(int n, int r){
        // code here
     enter code here    const unsigned int M = 1000000007;
        long long dp[n+1]={0},i,ans;
        if(n<r)
        return 0;
        dp[0]=1;
        dp[1]=1;
        for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
        dp[i]=i*dp[i-1];
        }
        ans=(dp[n])/(dp[n-r]*dp[r]);
      ans=ans%M;
      return ans;
        
    }
};
```

don't really understand what is going on. The division seems to be well defined.

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Goodluck 

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

> The division seems to be well defined.

You are right suspecting the division as the SIGFPE error origin. As you know, division is well defined as long as the divisor is not zero. At first glance, one wouldn't expect that `dp[n-r]*dp[r]` could become zero. But the elements of `dp` have a limited range of values they can hold. With a 64-bit `long long`, the maximum representable value typically is 2<sup>63</sup>−1 = 9223372036854775807. This means that `dp[i]` already has overflown for `i` > 20, though on common processors this overflow is silently ignored. Now, as computing the factorial by multiplication with even higher values of `i` proceeds, more and more zeros are "shifted in" from the right until eventually all 64 bits are zero; this is on common processors for `i` = 66 where the exception occurs when `n-r` or `r` are equal to or greater than 66.